# Why List is faster than Dict on the same python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've wrote a function about dynamic programming.

The recursion formula is

> T(n) = T(0) * T(n-1) + T(1) * T(n-2) + … + T(n-1) * T(0)

As you can see, the value of `T(n)` depends on the values of `T(0) … T(n-1)`.

In this problem, I need to store `T(0) … T(n-1)` for calculate `T(n)`.

But **which data structure is the best?**

> Assume we have finished calculate `T(0) … T(5)`. we need to calculate `T(6)`
>
> We can store T in the following structure:
>
> > `T = [1,1,2,5,14,42,0]`
> >
> > `T = {0:1,1:1,2:2,3:5,4:14,5:42,6:0}`

My answer is `dict` at first, because the time complexity of getting `T(k)` is `O(1)`.

However after test both of `list` and `dict`. The test result shows that `list` is faster than `dict`. 
**Why???**

I use `n = 1000` to test the program.

```
import timeit
def test(n, T):
    T[0] = 1
    # calculate T[i]
    # we need to calculate T[0]-> T[n-1] at first.
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
        for j in range(i):
            T[i] += T[j]*T[i-1-j]
    return T[n]

# initial list T
T_1 = [0]*1001 

# initial dict T
T_2 = {} 
for i in range(1001):
    T_2[i] = 0

t = timeit.timeit(stmt="test(1000,T_1)",setup="from __main__ import test,T_1;",number=10)
print("store T with list, total time is:",t)
t = timeit.timeit(stmt="test(1000,T_2)",setup="from __main__ import test,T_2;",number=10)
print("store T with dict, total time is:",t)
```

The running results are:

> store T with list, total time is: 6.454328614287078
>
> store T with dict, total time is: 6.761199993081391

Thanks for your help.

Comment: List access is also `O(1)`, but a somewhat *faster* `O(1)`

Comment: Both have (amortized) `O(1)` access, however the complexity of `O()` differs - in case of a `dict` there is an extra step of having to hash the input before doing a hash lookup whereas `list` can immediately find the memory location where a reference to the actual value is held. Both are `O(1)` in the sense that no matter the size the lookup is linear.

Comment: As a side comment, list and map implementation are dependent of the Python implementation and might vary from version too.

Comment: @zwer um, the time complexity *doesn't* differ. And I believe you meant the lookup is *constant*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - True, too late to edit now. The time complexity doesn't differ, but the actual lookup complexity does given the difference of implementation.

Comment: @zwer complexity isn't the correct word here, but simply the "run time". It's a pedantic point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** Dictionaries use hashing to look up a value which adds some overhead. There is also a probability of collision which costs a little more performance to resolve.

**Long answer:**

*Hashing:*
Dictionary is implemented as a hashtable, which is a data structure that stores values in an array internally. It determines which index to use by passing the key to a hashing function. The hashing function will produce a value within the range of the internal array. This is a relatively quick way to look up an item by key instead of index. But it's still slower than looking up directly by index due to the requirement to run this hashing function each time.

*Collisions:*
Dictionaries cannot perfectly avoid collisions in most cases. The internal array can either be implemented as an array of linked lists or another technique may be used to resolve collisions. It is possible to avoid collisions if the data set changes slowly, or never changes; create a perfect hash function for the given data set. There is no universal perfect hash function for all data sets, it is not possible. So generalized dictionaries such as the one provided in Python must implement collision resolution.

Which data structure is better? It depends on how your data is mapped.

If you can map it to consecutive integer keys (eg. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...) with very few gaps, then an array (list in python) may be the best option.

If your data set has non-integer keys, a dictionary is the best option. This is what it was designed for.

If you have integer keys with large gaps, a dictionary will save a lot of memory compared to a list, since the list would have to contain a lot of wasted indices.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python's bottom implementation. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: It's the most common implementation of a dictionary. This is something you should learn about in detail if you take a data structures course at college.